# OR-Tools CP-Sat with Pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, exe, or-tools, cp-sat

Model works pretty fine on my pc using VS Code. Once I create an exe with pyinstaller and try to run the .exe nothing works. A small window appears for 1 sec and nothing else. I also tried some tk msg box and nothing happens.

Here are the imports of my main :

```
import csv
import os 
import openpyxl
import sft_gen
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
```

The imports of my 2nd file (sft_gen):

```
import csv
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
```

When I run the .exe in the cmd prompt I get :
[Error msg in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUDjl.png)

Edit.1. : After testing, found out that :

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
```

is the reason why the .exe fails to execute.

What could be the solution to this? I really want to deploy my CP model to other users... In the meantime I'll try other .exe apps like py2exe and mention here if I have any success with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was asked before.
From what I understand, pyinstaller does not support python module using native libraries.